# Is there any possibility to exclude one of MuliSig Wallet owners?

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, multisignature

I mean not to exclude from already existin multi sig wallets, but create a wallet with such possibility.

For example:
   The team of 4 people want to accept temporary 5th member (give him the right to control the wallet on equal basis as others) for 2 month. But the initial group (of 4) should have a right to exclude him. Or even automaticaly after this time period this member should be excluded from the wallet owners group.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your contract to do this.